# Is there any way to delay rendering row in a grid in React?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'd like to ask that if there any way could delay rendering and displaying rows, meanwhile showing a loading overlay. I'm using react and ag-grid.  render Code is like below

```
   onGridReady(params) {

     this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi= params.columnApi
    this.datasource={
    getRows:this.getDatasetRows.bind()this
    params.api.setDatasource(this.dataSource)}

}
```

Comment: Do you want only the rows to have a render delay or the entire grid?

Comment: Hi, I only  want rows to have a render delay

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can update the rowdata after render instead of delay rendering.

Update Row Data

```
api.setRowData(newData)
```

Update Single Row / Cell

```
rowNode.setData(data)

rowNode.setDataValue(col,value)
```

[React Data Grid: Updating Data](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update/)